# It's mandatory to request user's permissions in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

I'm implementing angularfire but it's also a generic question.

I use RealTime Database and FCM modules. But, **I don't need to show browser or background notifications**, I'm just only communicating server with client sending push messages (for refreshing purposes only).

This current code is requesting user permissions on the browser. **It's possible to avoid this?**

```
this.afMessaging.requestToken
  .subscribe(
    token => {
      console.log('Permission granted! Save to the server!', token);
      this.updateFirebaseToken(token);
      this.updateAPIToken(token);
      },
    err => { console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err); }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is mandatory to ask for permission, even if you don't intend to show the user a notification. There's been an [even-more-recent question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403792/can-i-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-without-notification-permission-javascript) asking the same basic thing that has a couple good answers explaining why by people way smarter and more experienced than me.

In case anyone can't access that question in the future, I'll include Google Dev Adocate [Doug Stevenson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson) excellent concise explanation here of why it's required:

> It's to protect the user's preferences about what your app is allowed
>   to do. The way push messaging works on browsers is by using a service
>   worker. Even though you say you don't need a service worker, you are
>   actually making using of it when using Firebase Cloud Messaging in
>   your app.
>
> Given that, the prompt is necessary because the browser doesn't know
>   what you intend to do with that push message. If the user doesn't
>   trust your app, they should have the right to limit what it can
>   actually do, especially when they're not using your app. Mobile
>   operating systems (iOS, Android) are the same way.